# Dynamic cell reference SUBSTITUTE formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a form submitting new rows to a Google Sheet. I am submitting `=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(E2," ","-"))` as a cell formula directly into the adjacent F2.

The question is how to change `E2` for `E3, E4` etc as more rows are submitted through the form?

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Put this in `F2`

```
=Arrayformula(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(E2:E," ","-")))
```

Comment: Got this "Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in F3." and #REF! showing in the F column cells

Comment: @Netbuddy clear/delete everything in F column (top to bottom) and re-apply formula in F2

Comment: Woohoo! Awesome. Thanks for that formula, it seems its all good now.